# Call dynamic function name in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-function

Is it possible to call a function with a dynamic name in SQL?

For example:

```
SELECT functionid, (SELECT results FROM dbo.Function_*functionid*) AS results
FROM List_of_Functions
```

This would call a different function for every row in the table List_of_Functions.

Or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to build (either type it in, or build it dynamically based on your table) a SQL statement like:

```
SELECT
    functionid
        ,CASE  functionid
            WHEN 1 THEN dbo.Function_1()
            WHEN 2 THEN dbo.Function_2()
            WHEN 3 THEN dbo.Function_3()
         END AS results
    FROM List_of_Functions
```

Instead of building all those functions, wouldn't it be better to build one function, and pass in a value that the function can use to differentiate the processing?  like:

```
SELECT
    functionid
        ,dbo.Function(functionid) AS results
    FROM List_of_Functions_Parameters
```

Comment: Do you know if there will be any difference in performance for method 1 and 2?

Comment: @William, I have no idea how many functions you have or what they are actually doing.  thus, saying anything about performance would be a complete guesses.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to call a function with a dynamic name in SQL?

Not in pure SQL.

You can achieve this using dynamic SQL, but not without some risk, in particular that of [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

I suggest reading [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) by Erland Sommarskog for a comprehensive treatment of the subject.

Comment: But in the query I posted, the dynamic part of the functions name is coming from a value in SQL, not user input so how could anything be injected?

Comment: @William - And if something unwanted goes into your `List_of_Functions`? I am not saying it is a risk in _all_ cases, but that generally when using dynamic SQL, you need to keep this risk in mind.

Comment: In this case List_of_Functions is created by me so that isn't an issue. So this isn't possible at all with pure SQL? Do you know of any other ways I could approach this problem?

Comment: @William - Dynamic SQL is one of the easiest options.

Comment: @Oded In case of function Dynamic SQL is not the only option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50773766/5070879

Answer (score 1):

Just want to extend and oppose [Oded's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10557302/5070879):

> > **Is it possible to call a function with a dynamic name in SQL?**
>
> *Not in pure SQL.*
>
> *You can achieve this using dynamic SQL, but not without some risk, in particular that of SQL Injection.*

Yes, it is possible without using dynamic SQL.

Preparing:

```
CREATE TABLE List_of_Functions(functionid INT);
INSERT INTO List_of_functions(functionid) VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4);

CREATE FUNCTION Function_1()
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
   RETURN 'Return from Function_1';
END;

CREATE FUNCTION Function_2()
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
   RETURN 'Return from Function_2';
END;

CREATE FUNCTION Function_3()
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
   RETURN 'Return from Function_3';
END;
```

Core function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Function_dispatcher(@name SYSNAME)
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @r VARCHAR(100);
  IF OBJECT_ID(@name, N'FN') IS NULL  --handling non-existing function
    RETURN NULL;
  EXEC @r = @name; 
  RETURN @r;
END;
```

And final call:

```
SELECT *, dbo.Function_dispatcher(s.n) AS result
FROM List_of_Functions lf
OUTER APPLY(SELECT CONCAT('dbo.Function_', lf.functionid)) s(n);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=67e865227860df7a8abcee3c2c1f6e14)**

Output:

```
┌────────────┬────────────────┬────────────────────────┐
│ functionid │       n        │         result         │
├────────────┼────────────────┼────────────────────────┤
│          1 │ dbo.Function_1 │ Return from Function_1 │
│          2 │ dbo.Function_2 │ Return from Function_2 │
│          3 │ dbo.Function_3 │ Return from Function_3 │
│          4 │ dbo.Function_4 │ null                   │
└────────────┴────────────────┴────────────────────────┘
```

Using this approach you can avoid of changing main function every time new function will appear(CASE WHEN ...) like in [KM.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10557679/5070879)

Comment: Just wanted to add that it is possible to use this approach also for cases when the functions takes an argument. 
example:
`CREATE FUNCTION Function_dispatcher(@name SYSNAME, @someArgument INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @r VARCHAR(100);
  IF OBJECT_ID(@name, N'FN') IS NULL 
    RETURN NULL;
  EXEC @r = @name @someArgument;  
  RETURN @r;
END;`